# How to mask a column in a Pandas Dataframe while displaying it?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have a Dataframe:

```
    ID    Name         Salary($)
     0    Alex Jones     44,000
     1    Bob Smith      65,000
     2    Peter Clarke   50,000
```

In order to protect the privacy of the individuals in this dataset, I want to mask the output of this Dataframe in a Jupyter notebook like this:

```
    ID    Name         Salary($)
     0    AXXX XXXX     44,000
     1    BXX XXXXX     65,000
     2    PXXXX XXXXX   50,000
```

Individually replacing characters in each name seems very crude to me. There must be a better approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can concatenate the first character by the result of replace all characters in the remaining slice of each name using [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html#pandas.Series.str.replace):

```
In[16]:
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str[0] + df['Name'].str[1:].str.replace('\w','X')
df

Out[16]: 
   ID          Name Salary($)
0   0    AXXX XXXXX    44,000
1   1     BXX XXXXX    65,000
2   2  PXXXX XXXXXX    50,000
```

Comment: `df['Name'] = df['Name'].str[0]+df['Name'].str[1:].replace('[\w]','X',regex=True)` This was my answer :( I missed it .

Comment: The `[]` isn't necessary and I think that `regex=True` isn't required as it just accepts a pattern/regex object anyway

Comment: I agree to that as I saw your answer. But I almost had it. I didn't user `.str` so I cant get rid of regex=True :)

Comment: Usually too busy to answer these days but this seemed an interesting one to look at